# MySQL Erro: ER_TOO_LONG_KEY

Tags: mysql

Estou recebendo o erro no MySQL e não sei como resolvê-lo.

Abaixo está listado o output:

```
code: 'ER_TOO_LONG_KEY',
  errno: 1071,
  sqlMessage: 'Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'alter table `positions` add unique `positions_name_unique`(`name`)' 
}
```

Imagem da estrutura da tabela:
-> http://prntscr.com/jrdihn

O charset utilizado é UTF-8.

Comment: Insira na pergunta a estrutura da tabela, tipo, charset usado etc.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Acabei de tentar. Sem sucesso. O mesmo erro é recebido.

Comment: Tente um valor bem baixo mesmo, tipo name(20)

Comment: Ainda não funciona _(tinha mudado para 10)_.

Comment: O engraçado é que no meu computador funciona. É só no servidor que o erro existe. ._.

Comment: @dvd, acabou que era diminuindo mesmo... Acabei cometendo um engano na hora de diminuir e por isso comentei acima. _Pode colocar a resposta para marcar. :)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O máximo que você pode usar em colunas `utf8mb4` (em tabela INNODB) seria `191` (767/4 = 191) devido ele usar 4 bytes por caractere.

Diminua o valor em `name(200)` para que fique dentro do limite.

Mais informações você pode consultar a **[documentação oficial do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html)**.